# Order list item on Rails update with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a sidebar with a list of room names. You can edit a room's name in a modal. When you click update in the modal, the room name should be updated in the sidebar and it should appear in the proper order in the list. This will happen on refresh because of the server side Rails code. I just need to make it work on the client side.

It's all working fine except for the sorting. I've tried this in my update.js.erb file:

```
$("ul.rooms li").detach().sort(asc_sort).appendTo('ul.rooms');
function asc_sort(a, b){
    return ($(b).text()) < ($(a).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

That results in each list item appearing twice and the newly updated room sorts to the bottom of the list.

Here's what the HTML looks like for a list item (the room name is 1):

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="room" id="room-11">
      1
      <span class="badge counter"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="cog-link pull-right" style="padding:0 20px 0 2px;" data-remote="true" href="/rooms/11/edit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog pull-right"></i></a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this in Chrome was a nightmare so I ended up using tinysort to solve this issue: http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/